# How to pass mulitple record in Http Request Body parameter

Tags: jmeter

Perviously I am using single EmailId as Body Data Now my need is using different EmailId for each request.here below screentshot will clear the agenda.

[image: GetDeviceHttpRequest]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is using [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function:

1. Given you have a file with emails like:

   ```
   johndoe@example.com
   janedoe@example.com
   etc.
   ```
2. Substitute your request body to have `__StringFromFile()` function instead of the hard-coded email ID like:

   ```
   {"EmailId" : "${__StringFromFile(/path/to/your/file.txt,,,)}"}
   ```

---

Other options are in:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - if your email are in CSV file
- [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) - if your emails are in the database

Check out [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) to learn more about creating data-driven JMeter tests.

Answer (score 2):

Pratik,

You need to pass the email from external file [say CSV]. Please follow below steps:

1. Create a .csv file on Desktop with all your emails in new line as referred in the screenshot
   [image]
2. Now add 'CSV Data Set Config' element to the threadgroup and set the .csv file path:[image]
3. Pass the variable in your http request say '$EMAIL'

You can get the detailed information on CSV Data Set config element from here: [JMeter CSV Data Set Config](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/01/load-test-with-unique-users/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.